# Is it possible to get someone's ip address from message discord python

Tags: python, discord.py

Is it possible to get someone's IP address from a message on discord python?

Comment: What do the docs say?

Comment: discord python docs don't say anything about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not.  Discord, or similar cloud platforms, wouldn't reveal identifying information like a user's IP address through their API.

You'll be limited to the information provided via the [`User` model](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User).